# Tomcat, sendRedirect using absolute path not working

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have an web app with context root 'myapp'. and one servlet myapp/page1 and one jsp myapp/page2.jsp. From servlet I am redirecting to jsp using '`response.sendRedirect('/page2.jsp')`. It is failing. I have noticed that the request redirect is to '`http://localhost:8080/page2.jsp`' (context root is not being included in the URL). 
My understanding is that context root would be included by the container.
Env: Tomcat 7, web.xml version 3.0, 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're using a relative path. An absolute path to page2.jsp would be `"http://localhost:8080/"+request.getContextRoot()+"/page2.jsp"`. Another advantage of this approach is, if you should ever change your appserver, to say JBoss or WebLogic or whatever, you won't need to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

[hd1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802181/14081018) gave me a compile time error.

However, this worked for me:

`response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page2.jsp");`